# C++ force implementation of method?

Tags: c++, class, methods, abstract-class

I want to write an abstract class so whoever inherits it, he will be forced to implement a specific function inside it.

**For example I wrote:**

```
class Car {
    virtual double getFuelConsumption(int speed) = 0;
};
```

But If I write the following it compiles with **no compilation error** (even though it didn't implement getFuelConsumption())

```
class meme : public Car {};
```

---

Update:
Why I'm getting error:
(I know that if it's exactly a car then it doesn't have `getFuelConsumption` implemented what what if it's a class that inherits class `Car`, I want this to work)

```
double getPetrol(std::vector<Road> roads, const Car &car) {
car.getFuelConsumption(1);
}
```

```
> 'this' argument to member function 'getFuelConsumption' has type
> 'const Car', but function is not marked const
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a `meme` object?

Comment: I should only use virtual @cigien

Comment: That's fine. Have you tried declaring `meme x;` in `main`?

Comment: I know it will result in error but I want ti prevent inheriting without implementing

Comment: So you want `class X : meme { ...` to not compile because `meme` didn't implement the virtual function?

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: Maybe, but the first thing you must do, is edit the question to be clearer, otherwise it'll get closed.

Comment: @cigien Done, Can you take a look at my comments in the answers?

Comment: No you can not force the implementation of `getFuelConsumption()` in `meme`. Because the language allows you to defer implement to a subsequent derived class. The compiler will prevent you from crating  any objects that are only partially implemented though.

Comment: Thanks, may someone help with the new issue that was produced? (I can call the function only like this Car::getFuel(1) and not like this car1.getFuel(1)) @MartinYork

Comment: Please add *all* your clarifications to the question, not as comments.

Comment: Which part of the "`getFuelConsumption' has type 'const Car', but function is not marked const`" error message is unclear to you? The compiler's error message is self-explanatory, tells you exactly the reason for the compilation error, and it has nothing to do with virtual inheritance.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik where do you see getFuelConsumption is const?

Comment: In the error message you showed: "'this' argument to member function 'getFuelConsumption' has type 'const Car', but function is not marked const". That's the complete error message, and it's self-explanatory.

Comment: @zoorish For your question **where do you see getFuelConsumption is const?**, wll it is obvious that the function is not const and that the compiler error message tell you that you try to call a non const function from a const object (that is `const Car &car`). Your function should be `virtual double getFuelConsumption(int speed) const = 0;` or you should not pass a const object. **Deciding what should be const is part of the design of an application.**

Answer (score 5):

The code you wrote is OK, as long as nobody instanciates a `meme`. This is by design.

As far as the compiler is concerned, your plan might very well be:

```
class meme : public Car
{

};

class ConcreteMeme : public meme
{
    virtual double getFuelConsumption(int speed) {return 2.0;}
};
```

Since you may want intermediate interfaces, there's no issue. The problem shows only when you try to instanciate a class that has a pure virtual method. If the compiler were to prevent you from having `meme`, you'd end up in a situation where you can't have `ConcreteMeme`.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what you want for `meme` or what a `ConcreteMeme` is. I just wanted to show that maybe `meme` doesn't implement it but a further class down the chain does.

Comment: I have an issue with this, why I can't do car1. getFuelConsumption(1)?

Comment: what is `car1` ?

Comment: Car car1(); or a class that inherits car and it has getFuelConsumption for its members...

Comment: `Car car1();` is a function definition. A good compiler will warn about it:  `warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]`

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is fine, `meme` will not be usable at all without the pure virtual method(s) being implemented.  The only reason it compiles now is that you haven't actually tried to use it.

Comment: I have an issue with this, why I can't do car1. getFuelConsumption(1)?

Comment: You can.  Have you tried?  Did you get an error message?  If so, post the complete code and the error message.

Comment: I can write Car:: getFuelConsumption(1); but not: Car c1; c1. getFuelConsumption(1);

Comment: Did you get an error message? If so, post the complete code and the error message.